# DateTime.now().toUtc().difference and DateTime.now().difference give the same result in dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Basically the title.
I want to get the difference between a dateTime and the current time. The date is in UTC there I first converted the current time into UTC and then found the difference. But the difference in both the cases, with or without converting to UTC is the same, while that should not be the case.

```
 print(DateTime.now().toUtc());
    print(DateTime.now());
    print(DateTime.now().toUtc()
        .difference(dateFormat.parse(comment.postedOn))
        .inMinutes);
    print( DateTime.now()
        .difference(dateFormat.parse(comment.postedOn))
        .inMinutes);
```

And the result is

I/flutter (20796): 2020-07-01 15:33:46.221975Z

I/flutter (20796): 2020-07-01 21:03:46.222207

I/flutter (20796): 361

I/flutter (20796): 361

Comment: `DateTime.now().toUtc()` and `DateTime.now()` both represent the same moment in time, just reported differently.  The difference between that moment in time and another moment in time should be the same regardless of timezones, so the observed behavior sounds correct to me.  Can you provide examples what you want?

Answer (score 3):

After doing some digging through the source code of the Dart SDK, it looks like either the `millisecondsSinceEpoch` property or the `microsecondsSinceEpoch` property is used to calculate the difference between two `DateTime` variables. This would explain why the difference is the same for both the UTC `DateTime` value and the local `DateTime` value, because they both represent the same time.

```
final now = DateTime.now();
final utc = now.toUtc();
final date = DateTime.parse('2020-07-01T19:00:00Z');

print(utc);
print(now);
print(date);
print(utc.microsecondsSinceEpoch);
print(now.microsecondsSinceEpoch);
print(date.microsecondsSinceEpoch);

print(utc.difference(date).inMinutes);
print(now.difference(date).inMinutes);
```

```
2020-07-01 16:26:54.464Z

2020-07-01 17:26:54.464

2020-07-01 19:00:00.000Z

1593620814464000

1593620814464000

1593630000000000

-153

-153
```

[./sdk/lib/core/date_time.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/7d863d7266bff796480aa31c3418528e8fc35f25/sdk/lib/core/date_time.dart#L149-L156)

```
/**
 * The value of this DateTime.
 *
 * The content of this field is implementation dependent. On JavaScript it is
 * equal to [millisecondsSinceEpoch]. On the VM it is equal to
 * [microsecondsSinceEpoch].
 */
final int _value;
```

[./js_runtime/lib/core_patch.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/1596bf3cd4f616e6624ef11c7b0b97350492c2bf/sdk/lib/_internal/js_runtime/lib/core_patch.dart#L324-L327)

```
@patch
Duration difference(DateTime other) {
  return new Duration(milliseconds: _value - other._value);
}
```

[./vm/lib/date_patch.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/9ae1448ef008ae60b1130ed63cd597af15bb7515/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/date_patch.dart#L199-L202)

```
@patch
Duration difference(DateTime other) {
  return new Duration(microseconds: _value - other._value);
}
```

If you do not want this default behaviour, then you could check to see if the `DateTime` value `isUtc`. If the value is not UTC, then you could add the `timeZoneOffset` to achieve your intended behaviour.

```
extension DateTimeExtensions on DateTime {
  Duration differenceTimeZoneOffset(DateTime other) {
    if (this.isUtc) {
      return this.difference(other);
    } else {
      return this.add(this.timeZoneOffset).difference(other);
    }
  }
}

final now = DateTime.now();
final utc = now.toUtc();
final date = utc.add(Duration(hours: 1));

print(utc);
print(now);
print(date);
print(utc.microsecondsSinceEpoch);
print(now.microsecondsSinceEpoch);
print(date.microsecondsSinceEpoch);

print(utc.differenceTimeZoneOffset(date).inMinutes);
print(now.differenceTimeZoneOffset(date).inMinutes);
```

```
2020-07-01 17:24:54.923Z

2020-07-01 18:24:54.923

2020-07-01 18:24:54.923Z

1593624294923000

1593624294923000

1593627894923000

-60

0
```

Comment: Any idea on how I can find the difference correctly then?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an additional code sample showing how you could achieve your intended behaviour instead of the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the difference of the `Duration` between local and UTC date times,
Try this.

```
DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset

//Maybe just check if the current time zone = UTC
bool isCurrentTimeZoneUTC() {
  final timeZoneOffset = DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset;
  return timeZoneOffset == Duration.zero;
}
```